# Cant connect by SSH and Webgui to ESX host

Tags: vmware-esxi, vmware-vsphere, vmware-vcenter

After a reboot of our vcenter server, one of the ESX hosts went disconnected from everything else. I cant seem to connect to it in any way. Ssh doesn't work, and the webgui also don't work.

(edit in error) It gives the following error when trying to connect the host by name or IP adress:
`Cannot contact the specified host (172.16.91.51). The host may not be available on the network, a network configuration problem may exist, or the management services on this host may not be responding.`

Ping requests do work to the host and the VM's it contains. We are an inexperienced team with this, so we are really in the dark right now.

Does anyone have a suggestion?? Feel free to ask for more info on the case, cause I dont know what I should post here initially.

Thanks in Advance,

Henri

Comment: Take a look at the local console of the machine.

Comment: Check if the host in question have kind of service processor and try to connect to this processor. Or if you have physical access to the machine check the status LEDs, cables, etc.

Comment: Local console doesnt work. I dont have access to the machines as it is located in a DC. I am at a point where the only option seems to go there and access/reboot the machine this way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I have been to the DC and rebooted the ESXi-host machine there after ssh and rdp to the VM's to shut them down. This resolved the issues as every services where restarted. I also documented the iDRAC IP-addresses (They where never documented) from the hosts in the cluster so we can access them remotely in the future.